# php-скрипт. Поиск по локальной сети

Tags: скрипт, поиск, php, сеть

Доброго всем времени суток!

Подскажите,пожалуйста, как с помощью php сделать поиск именно по локальной(компьютерной) сети?

Найти надо веб-сервера, но я думаю, найдя команду просто для поиска по сети,не сложно будет понять какие аргументы написать, чтобы был поиск именно веб-серверов.

Google в первые ничего не дал)) или я просто плохо искал...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перебор всех локальных IP, у каждого IP проверка нескольких портов (обычно 80, 8080, 443). С помощью сокетов :-) Что-то вроде:

```
$start = "1.1.1.1";
$end = "255.255.255.255";

for ($i=ip2long($start); $i<=ip2long($end); $i++){
    $adress = long2ip($i);
    $fp = @fsockopen($adress, 80, $errno, $errstring, 0.01);
    if($fp !== false) {
        $array[] = $adress; 
    }

    @fclose($fp);
}

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Чувствую себя таким дураком)) как говориться, слона-то мы и не заметили=)

мне кажется, или в цикле в функции fsockopen вместо $ftp_host надо указать $adress ?

И еще вопрос: в задании написано по протоколу HTTP... я вот лично только два протокола знаю:TCP и UDP. Т.е. TCP и UDP еще деляться? и внутри TCP есть HTTP?

Comment: @Автостопом_до_Рая поправил :-) Если по протоколу http, хм, хрен его знает. Попробуйте заменить fsockopen на file_get_contents() и поэкспериментировать.

Comment: Пробовал на Denwer'e .

echo $pf=pfsockopen('127.0.0.1',80,$error,$error2,2)."</BR>";
echo "error= ".$error." ".$error2;

Всегда возвращает:
 Resource id #2
 error= 0

Порт этот(проверил в httpd.conf ).
Причем и с другими адресами такой же ответ=)

Внимание,вопрос!
Почему?

Comment: хм...а может денвер не любит работать с сокетами?

Comment: Что касается протоколов: [Протокол передачи данных][1]


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85